# Problem with Data in Qlik Expression Editor - Want data after a specific date

Tags: qliksense, qlik-expression

I am trying to fetch Data i.e. Booking Data after a specific Booking Date and filtering with 3 order statuses by writing the below code in the Expression Editor

```
Count({<NewOrderStatus={'Cancelled','Active','Delivered'},Booking_date = {'$(>=2023-02-21)'}>} NewOrderStatus)
```

However, it is returning Blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[Booking_date]` field should have its set modifier formatted like this:

`Booking_date={">=2023-02-21"}`

But make sure you're using the same date format there as is used in the `[Booking_date]` field. If those dates are in `M/D/YYYY` format, for example, then your set modifier should look like this:

`Booking_date={">=2/21/2023"}`